# How to Object.assign() for specific properties in array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

****I created a form using JSON in vuejs with vuetify components. Whatever I fill in the form fields it stores in firebase. It generates data-table after submitting the form. If I want to edit one row I need to get form open and get data in the form fields.****

Here is my array of data:

```
fields: [{
            type_one: "text",
            label_one: "First Name",
            model_one: "",
            required_one: true,
            rules_one: [
                v => !!v || 'First name is required',
            ],
            type_two: "text",
            label_two: "Last Name",
            model_two: "",
            required_two: true,
            rules_two: [
                v => !!v || 'Last name is required',
            ],
        }, {
            type_one: "text",
            label_one: "Login Name",
            required_one: true,
            model_one: '',
            rules_one: [
                v => !!v || 'Login name is required',
            ],
            type_two: "select",
            label_two: "Customer Name",
            model_two: "",
            required_two: true,
            values: ["Customer 1", "Customer 2"],
            rules_two: [
                v => !!v || 'Customer name is required',
            ],
        }, {
            type_one: "text",
            label_one: "Phone",
            required_one: false,
            model_one: '',
            type_two: "text",
            label_two: "E-mail",
            model_two: "",
            required_two: true,
            rules_two: [
                v => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
                v => /^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid'
            ],
        }, {
            type_one: "password",
            label_one: "Password",
            required_one: true,
            model_one: '',
            rules_one: [
                v => !!v || 'Please enter the password',
            ],
            e1: true,
            type_two: "password",
            label_two: "Confirm Password",
            model_two: "",
            required_two: true,
            rules_two: [
                v => !!v || 'Please confirm the password',
            ],
        }, {
            type_one: "date",
            label_one: "Start Date",
            required_one: true,
            model_one: null,
            menu_one: false,
            rules_one: [
                v => !!v || 'Start Date is required',
            ],
            type_two: "date",
            label_two: "End Date",
            model_two: null,
            required_two: false,
            menu_two: false,
        }, {
            type_one: "text",
            label_one: "Login Expiry(In Days)",
            required_one: false,
            model_one: '',
            type_two: "checkbox",
            label_two: "Is Approval User",
            model_two: '',
            required_two: false,
        }, {
            type_one: "select",
            label_one: "Language",
            values: ["English", "French", "Italic"],
            required_one: false,
            model_one: '',
            type_two: "switch",
            label_two: "Grantee Allowed",
            model_two: '',
            required_two: true,
        }, {
            type_one: "description",
            label_one: "Description",
            required_one: false,
            model_one: ''
        }]
```

I am trying to assign new item getting from api to only **model_one** and **model_two** in the above array like **this.fields = Object.assign({}, item)**.
How to achieve that? please help.

Here is my data from API

```
item: [
{
firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            loginName: '',
            customerName: '',
            phone: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            confirmPassword: '',
            startDate: '',
            endDate: '',
            loginExpiry: '',
            approval: '',
            lang: '',
            grantee: '',
            description: ''
}
]
```

Please help. Thank You.

Comment: but `fields` is an **Array**, and `item` has no model_one/model_two, that seems to exist in `fields` already ... perhaps if you provide, **in the quetion**, an example of ... input data, what you've actually tried, expected output data

Comment: for specific fields i use var obj = ((field1, field2..)=>(field1, field2..))(oldObj)

Comment: btw, why `!!` in context of logical OR, the value is treated as truthy/falsy value? without it yields the same.